# Return value of an AWS (Java) Lambda function

Tags: java, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

Suppose I have the following code

```java
    public final class MyLambdaFunction implements RequestHandler<SQSEvent, String> {
           @Override
        public String handleRequest(SQSEvent event, Context context) {
           return "Hello World";
        }
    }
```

I don't understand the purpose of having an output value (a String, in the example above), so I was wondering if I can use that value somewhere else (e.g. automatically send the return value to another SQS queue)?

Comment: If you call a lambda function synchronously that is what is returned to the caller. For asynchronous invocations a return value makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what is written in [documentation](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-java-libs/blob/master/aws-lambda-java-core/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/lambda/runtime/RequestHandler.java) you might update return type to match your class like

```java
public final class MyLambdaFunction implements RequestHandler<SQSEvent, MyClass> {
    @Override
    public MyClass handleRequest(SQSEvent event, Context context) {
        MyClass myClassInstance = new MyClass();
        return myClassInstance;
    }
}
```

This is due to `RequestHandler` being a lambda and being able to answer to Http requests (and returning complex objects simplifies development).
However, to automatically send to another SQS queue you might use SQS sdk in your lambda to publish in another one before returning `myClassInstance`.

Keep in mind that `RequestHandler` is generic to handle any usecase not only  `SQSEvent`